# Oracle 11g r2 + How to generate unique id combing other fields?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
Create table person (
  LastName varchar(255),
  FirstName varchar(255),
  seq_num int
)

Create table address (
  Address varchar(255),
  City varchar(255),
  seq_num int
)
```

I need to generate a csv file, one of the fields is called unique_id combining with 4 fields.

Have a look at the query.

```
select
  GENERATE_ID(LastName, FirstName, Address, City) AS unique_id,
  LastName,
  FirstName,
  Address,
  City
from
  person,
  address
where
  person.seq_num = address.seq_num
```

How do I make the GENERATE_ID or any equivalent method?

Comment: This unique_id just need to be unique for those columns? If the value is same in two rows then unique id will also be same? is it just unique or do the value have to be the function of the passed 4 column values?

Comment: The above just an example. I will make sure that we have enough columns to make it unique.

Comment: Generate a UUID?  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions153.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using ORA_HASH?

```
select
  ora_hash(LastName || FirstName || Address || City) AS unique_id,
  LastName,
  FirstName,
  Address,
  City
from
  person,
  address
where
  person.seq_num = address.seq_num;
```

This way the ID stays the same for subsequent exports.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
select
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LastName, FirstName, Address, City ORDER BY LastName, FirstName) AS unique_id,
  LastName,
  FirstName,
  Address,
  City
from person 
   join address on person.seq_num = address.seq_num
```

But note, if you have more than one person with the same name and address/city the number is not unique anymore.
Otherwise just use `ROWNUM`

Answer (score 0):

There are four columns in the final table (result), if the records are unique based on those four columns, I think the simple way to generate a key is just concat them together.

```
select
LastName||FirstName||Address||City AS unique_id,
  LastName,
  FirstName,
  Address,
  City
from
  person,
  address
where
  person.seq_num = address.seq_num
```